# Make table row scroll up and down in some period of time automatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I have create a list of Currency exchange rate by using table with 6 row.
i want 6 row to have some animation like it running up and down automatically in some period of time so it can make user user more attractive on it.

please give me some example or if you have any idea to make table row animation that make more attractive for user.

Answer (score 0):

Move the scrolled position of your view.

**public void scrollBy (int x, int y)**

**Parameters**

x - the amount of pixels to scroll by horizontally

y - the amount of pixels to scroll by vertically

```
lv.scrollBy(100,100)  //....like this
```

Comment: Can you give more example,,,I am not so specialize about java. Please help:

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="GOLDEN ROYAL EXCHANGE"
            android:textColor="#ba8707"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
            android:shadowColor="#030303"
            android:phoneNumber="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="1sp"
        android:background="@drawable/lineback"
        android:layout_weight="0.62">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myScrollview"
            android:scrollbars="none">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:background="#4042dba8"
                android:id="@+id/khmerrow"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="145px"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/khmerflages" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                    android:text="Khmer Riel 柬币"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="USD/KHR"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="4,200"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#4042dba8"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="145px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thaiflags" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Thai Baht 泰铢"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:text="USD/THB"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="35"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#4042dba8"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="145px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/chinaflags" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="China RMB 人民币"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:text="USD/RMB"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="6.7"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#4042dba8"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="145px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/hongkongflags" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="HongKong Dollar 港币"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="USD/HKD"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="8.7"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#4042dba8"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="145px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/malaysiaflags" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Malaysia MYR 马币"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="USD/MYR"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="6.6"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#4042dba8"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="145px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/singaporeflags" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Singapore SGD 新币"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="USD/SGD"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="1.6"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/date" />


        </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="1sp"
        android:background="#dee6d461"
        android:layout_weight="0.36">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/bckgrndViewFlipper1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/exchange1" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/exchange2" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/exchange3" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/exchange4" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/exchange5" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/exchange6" />
        </ViewFlipper>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/trading"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="Trading Hours .................`enter code here`"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#ba8707"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Animation fade_in, fade_out, rowanimation;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
ScrollView myView;
TextView date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.bckgrndViewFlipper1);
    fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);
    fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(fade_in);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fade_out);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();


}
```

}